# Keras LSTM for text prediction does not learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to train a keras LSTM model as follows:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.LSTM(256))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# define the checkpoint
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-bigger.hdf5"
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
# fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50, batch_size=100, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

The model should predict chess games. For example a parsed and coded chess game is as follows:

```
[3379, 905, 2967, 4705, 4569, 8954, 6732, 5282, 9178, 9052, 486, 1665, 2459, 3736, 1444, 9409, 5841, 10023, 9484, 5841, 5541, 2605, 2178, 7843, 4679, 7242, 4755, 4755, 3530, 64, 6468, 407, 5105, 8224, 2892, 3736, 9026, 3819, 5592, 9178, 5862, 5845, 4246, 8380, 9324, 4778, 4341, 2068, 344, 9004, 7089, 2180, 6549, 2174, 9754, 8602, 4339, 7291, 7291, 9968, 7920, 8392, 6004, 7516, 6541, 9409, 6215, 2263, 5098, 2672, 8573, 6537, 7073, 4551, 9004]
```

my x and y are like this:
X identifies splits every 5 moves

```
#X:
[[3379, 905, 2967, 4705, 4569] [905, 2967, 4705, 4569, 8954] [2967, 4705, 4569, 8954, 6732] ... [2672, 8573, 6537, 7073, 4551]]
```

Y is the list of moves that must be guessed at the end of each set of moves

```
#Y:
[3379, 905, 2967, 4705, 4569, 8954, 6732 ... 2672, 8573, 6537, 7073, 4551, 9004]
```

subsequently Y was encoded in base5 as follows:

```
[[3 1   0   1   3   2] [1   1   0   1   2   1] [2   1   0   1   3   4] ... ]
```

The model doesn't learn anything, the first time I tried to make the model.fit with 100 epochs and a batch_size of 64 using normalised X but the loss value grew a lot, at the first epoch the loss value was 0.56 while at the last it was 266.50...
I tried to remove the normalization and make the model.fit with 50 epochs and a batch_size of 100 and now the results are stable. At the first epoch the loss value is 36.11 while the accuracy is 0.316, at the 50th epoch the loss value is 46.80 and the accuracy is 0.317.

Does anyone know why my model does not learn?

UPDATE 24/01/22: 
After @MarcelB's comment I publish the results with 1 sample and 10 samples.
I changed the batch_size value of my model to 5 from 100.
On the following picture I have the graphs of my train with 1 sample:
[train with 1 sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPluR.png)

I don't know if it's right but the 10 samples (10 matches) I put together as one big match.
On the following picture I have the graphs of my train with 10 sample:
[train with 10 sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtQ5D.png)

Comment: Could you share your input data?

Comment: @robocat314 In the question I put my input, with only one game, in my dataset I have almost 2 million. I'm testing the model for now I'm going to pass it the first 2000 games side by side as if it were one big game, is that correct? So the X will be a list containing all the games divided into 5 moves but without actually dividing the games but putting them all together.
for example. [[first 5 moves of the first game] ... [last 5 moves of the first game] ... [first 5 moves of the last game] ... [last 5 moves of last game]]. Whereas Y will have the individual moves to be predicted all at once.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what are you trying to do. If maybe you are trying to learn how to use LSTMs I would suggest you to find some tutorial examples first, to get a grasp of what LSTMs and deep learning is in general capable of.

Comment: I didn't look at your code in detail but can you overfit your model on 1 sample? On 10 samples? This way you can exclude you have a bug somewhere. Can you post graphs of the training procedure? What can always happen is that your data is not expressive enough or your dataset is too small. Do you know if a sequential model can be fitted to this?

Comment: Hi @MarcelB, Thanks for your reply! I have updated the question with the graphs!

Comment: I think you're showing validation/test graphs no? What I meant is observe the _training_ loss. Does it go to 0 when training on 1 sample? It should be because the model will overfitted to only this thing, right?

Comment: Hi @MarcelB, No the graphs I have published show train accuracy and train loss with 1 and 10 games, in fact my problem is right here, even with only 1 game my model is not overfitting. I didn't pass any validation set to my model but only the train set to make it overfitting but I didn't get it.

Comment: Okay, that may indicate that your data is not appropriate for learning it. But I am not 100% sure, I am not a domain expert and barely know anything about chess. You can probably judge better.

Comment: Ok thank you very much @MarcelB for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Dropout is used to interfere with the learning process by deactivating a specific number of neurons or connections randomly during each epoch. You have two dropouts in your model, that means, after your LSTM layers about 20% of the inputs for the next layer are deactivated, which can seriously diminish the performance. You should not include dropouts if your model does not overfit. Remove these layers and check again.

https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am trying your solution but the values have dropped, the loss has now increased compared to the first epoch and stands at a value of 24.30 while the accuracy is stuck at 0.13